# How to implement animations when you hover over a button

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

Im currently trying to implement this animation when you hover over a button:
https://codepen.io/webLeister/pen/XwGENz

I want it to only work upon hovering over the + not the text in my button.
here is the button code, it is a .svg:

```
<button class="bubble-animation">Add more 
<svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 7L14 7" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1.5"/>
<path d="M7 14L7 -7.15256e-07" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1.5"/>
</svg>
</button>
```

I don't want it to twist to the side or anything, just the hover animation.
Does anyone know how i would go about doing this?

Comment: Use CSS animation or SMIL. There's nothing in your current example to animate anything so where are you stuck?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The latter needs to be contained directly inside your question, not just dumped onto an external platform. Currently, your question does not even contain the part that is actually primarily relevant here - the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to only work upon hovering over the + not the text in my button.

The plus, that is actually an arrow, you mean ...?

Currently, the bubbles moving are triggered on hover over the button, by this part:

```
.button{
  &_inner{
    &:hover .button_spots{ ... }
```

That whole last part `&:hover .button_spots{ /*...*/ }` needs to be triggered by hovering on the `i` icon now, so it a) needs to be moved into `.button{ &_inner{ i.l{ ... }}}`, and b) the selector needs to be modified - currently it just selects `.button_spots` *ancestors* of the button itself, but these elements are not ancestors of the `i` element. So we need to target the `.b_l_quad` *sibling* of the icon first, and then the bubbles inside that:

```
&:hover ~ .b_l_quad .button_spots { ... }
```

Somehow the codepen always messes it up when I try to fork it, but here is the full modified version of your SCSS: https://pastebin.com/8tTQw9Ru

Answer (score 0):

Here you can add class to ***svg*** and change the ***button_inner*** class in your reference code.

or you can wrap svg in an div and trigger hover on it.

This means change ***.button_inner:hove**r* in that code to ***.hovered:hover***

And dont forget to add ***button_spots*** divs if you want those dots effect in background.

> *Add More* will not shift to side as in the refferece code downloads is in a *span* so it will not affect Add More

```
<button class="bubble-animation">Add more 
<svg class='hovered' width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 7L14 7" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1.5"/>
<path d="M7 14L7 -7.15256e-07" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1.5"/>
</svg>
</button>
```

or

```
<button class="bubble-animation">Add more 
<div class='hovered'>
<svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 7L14 7" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1.5"/>
<path d="M7 14L7 -7.15256e-07" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1.5"/>
</svg>
 <div class='b_l_quad'>
        <div class='button_spots'></div>
        <div class='button_spots'></div>
</div
</div>
</button>
```

*2nd option would be better*